# How do I define generators in Minitab

Tags: experiment-design

How do I define generators in Minitab 16?

I have an experiment design (DOE) with 5 factors and 2 generators.

I entered  D=ABC  E=AC  in the box of generators  but it says only F through G ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please do not write all caps. Also, you should probably add more information to the question (what are you trying to do, what errors you get).

Answer (score 1):

You are **adding** factors to the base design. Those added factors must be in alphabetical order following the base design.

I gather that you have specified the base design as 5 factors which have taken codes A:E so added factors must start at F.

I guess that you have "5 factors **including** 2 generators" so you should specify your base design with only three factors and specify the fourth and fifth via the generators.